# Looping the Function cause it unresponsive in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is the code that i tried for snow flakes. Everything seems ok but once the certain period of time that script get unresponsive means (It slow down the browser firefox). 
I am not sure why this should happen.
How can i make it as responsive without cause anything to browser.
Here is **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/7BFCM/3/)**

How can i make it responsive script which doesn't cause any.!
I think I made a mistake in looping the javascript function :( 
Any Suggestion Would Be great.

Thanks

**Javascript:**

```
// window.setInterval(generateSnow, 0);
var windowHeight = jQuery(document).height();
var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
function generateSnow() {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var snowTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight));
        snowTop = 0;

        var snowLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowWidth - 2));
        var imageSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

        jQuery('body').append(
            jQuery('<div />')
                .addClass('snow')
                .css('top', snowTop)
                .css('left', snowLeft)
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .html('*')
        );
    }
}


function snowFalling() {
    jQuery('.snow').each(function(key, value) {
        if (parseInt(jQuery(this).css('top')) > windowHeight - 80) {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
        var fallingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        var movingDirection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var currentTop = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('top'));
        var currentLeft = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('left'));
        jQuery(this).css('top', currentTop + fallingSpeed);
        if (movingDirection === 0) {
            jQuery(this).css('bottom', currentLeft + fallingSpeed);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).css('bottom', currentLeft + -(fallingSpeed));
        }
    });
}

window.setInterval(snowFalling, 15);
window.setInterval(generateSnow, 1000);
```

Comment: Not a full answer, hence it's only a comment, but you don't need to script the movement like that.  You can use css transitions or jQuery animate.  Just create the snowflake and set the animation type and length, with a callback to remove it at the end.  Much easier than the above, and will not have any responsiveness issues (unless you get silly :p)

Comment: As an aside, this sort of application would be much better suited to using an HTML canvas rather than DOM manipulation.

Comment: I've tried to optimize your solution by reducing the number of dom insertions, switching from absolute to fixed positioning, and by performing animations on browser animation frames. http://jsfiddle.net/7BFCM/7/ This is still cpu intesive so I'd google for some canvas solution.  http://www.techumber.com/2013/01/HTML5-Canvas-Tutorial-On-Creating-Snowfall-Effect.html

Comment: @Archer note that each snow flake moves _randomly_ in each frame.

Comment: @Alnitak That's fine and a doddle.  Animations can be created on-the-fly very easily - direction, speed, intermittent movement.  It could all be done with 1 function that is run periodically and (probably) at the end of a snowflakes animation (start it again, differently, elsewhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding and removing *lots* of elements on the page during runtime, making browsers refresh the structure of that page frequently.

That approach is:

1. the worst thing you can do performance-wise
2. probably making the browser fall to its knees once enough DIVs have been generated, removed, generated, removed, generated, removed......

A mobile browser would probably just freeze after 2 seconds with this config.

I recommend pre-generating all DIVs right at the beginning, re-using them and using CSS animations or jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

As @ZathrusWriter mentioned, you should re-use your snowflake elements so memory does not bloat.

The reason the browser starts to get slow after creating a bunch of snowflakes is because JavaScript manages memory using a `garbage collector`. Thus the memory is getting freed much slower than you're allocating memory for new snowflakes. Ideally, you want to allocate memory for all the snowflakes once.

Basically, create the elements for the number of snowflakes you want on screen at any given time. Place them all on the screen in random locations to start. Then once a snowflake goes off-screen or invisible, that snowflake is usable again. So you'll move it back to the top (possibly in another random location) and make it fall like a snowflake again (instead of deleting it and creating a new one).

This is one step away from creating a particle emitter.